# Ejecutar en la consola de python

Tags: python, pycharm

Cada vez que le doy a un programa para ejecutar en pycharm (lo hago en la consola de predeterminado), me abre una consola nueva para cada ejecución. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar eso para que se ejecute en la misma ventana de la consola y no vaya creando cada vez una pestaña nueva?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3):

Vale ya lo encontré, si alguien lo necesita dejo aquí como se hace:

1. Vas a las opciones y buscas "Builds, Executions, Deployment"
2. Clickas en "Console"
3. Activas la opción de "Use existing console for Run with Python Console".